# submit changes made to input data loaded from text file

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a text file with some data, that I am passing into some inputs in a form

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="edit_subjects.php" method="post">
    <?php
    $content = file('../db/test.txt');
    foreach($content as $eachLine) {
        list($subject, $type, $description) = explode('|', $eachLine);
        echo '<label for="subject">Subject:</label>';
        echo '<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="'.$subject.'"><br>';
        echo '<label for="type">Type:</label>';
        echo '<input type="text" name="type" id="type" value="'.$type.'"><br>';
        echo '<label for="description">Description:</label><br>';
        echo '<textarea name="description" id="description">'.$description.'</textarea><br>';
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Running the code gives this output:

```
<label for="subject">Subject:</label>
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Subject 1"><br>
<label for="type">Type:</label>
<input type="text" name="type" id="type" value="Type1"><br>
<label for="description">Description:</label><br>
<textarea name="description" id="description">Description1
</textarea><br>

<label for="subject">Subject:</label>
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Subject 2"><br>
<label for="type">Type:</label>
<input type="text" name="type" id="type" value="Type2"><br>
<label for="description">Description:</label><br>
<textarea name="description" id="description">Description2
</textarea><br>

<label for="subject">Subject:</label>
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Subject 3"><br>
<label for="type">Type:</label>
<input type="text" name="type" id="type" value="Type3"><br>
<label for="description">Description:</label><br>
<textarea name="description" id="description">Description3
</textarea><br>
```

As you can see the names go again over and over, so how would I access each set of inputs individually and write it to the file

Comment: you would do that in edit_subjects.php - or is this a self referencing form?

Comment: I understand i would do it edit_subjects.php, but I have no idea how to do it

Comment: ok one second and I'll post a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution for edit_subjects.php:

If you are going to print the form items out in a loop like that, and then send them when the form is submitted, you need to change the `name=` value on each loop. You could use and incremental number like this:

```
$i = 1;

foreach($content as $eachLine) {
        list($subject, $type, $description) = explode('|', $eachLine);
        echo '<label for="subject">Subject:</label>';
        echo '<input type="text" name="subject' . $i .'" id="subject" value="'.$subject.'">br>';
        echo '<label for="type">Type:</label>';
        echo '<input type="text" name="type' . $i .'" id="type" value="'.$type.'"><br>';
        echo '<label for="description">Description:</label><br>';
        echo '<textarea name="description' . $i .'" id="description">'.$description.'</textarea><br>';
        $i++
    }
```

**OR** you can turn your form `name`s into arrays:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="subject[]" id="subject" value="'.$subject.'">
```

which will require you to loop over them in edit_subjects.php to get the values.

Then , Access your form values from the $_POST array (please bear in mind your should escape all values) :

```
    if (isset($_POST['subject'])
    {
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $type = $_POST['type'];
        //your other form values here...
        $result = $subject . "," . $type //or however you want to structure it
        $file = fopen("../db/test.txt", "w");
        fwrite($file, $result);
    } else {
        echo "POST variables not set!";
        die;
    }
```

An example for accessing your POST values if you use arrays is:

```
if (isset($_POST['subject'])
    {
        $file = fopen("../db/test.txt", "w");
        $i = 0;

        foreach($_POST['subject'] as $array)
        {
           $result = $_POST['subject'][$i] . "," . $_POST['type'][$i] ."\r\n";
           fwrite($file, $result);
           $i++
        }


    } else {
        echo "POST variables not set!";
        die;
    }
```

Comment: The thing is the inputs names go over and over again, so that will only submit the last set of inputs

Comment: Would would I write them all to a file then?

Comment: @RHNorskov Im not sure what you're last question means, please rephrase

Comment: If i used arrays as names how would I access and write them?

Comment: I have not been available since last I commented, tho I have accepted your answer now.

Answer (score 0):

In the file edit_subjects.php you have to read in the passed parameters with $_POST['subject'], ... Then join the variables in a string of the right format ($result) and write it back with the following code:

```
$fp = fopen("../db/test.txt", "r+");
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
    ftruncate($fp, 0);      
    fwrite($fp, $result);
    fflush($fp);           
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    
} else {
    echo "Couldn't get the lock!";
}
fclose($fp);
```